# Send a recordset to another macro

Tags: sql, excel, vba, recordset

I have a macro for updating an SQL table in an Excel Add-in. 
In order to use the same macro from multiple files I want to be able to create the recordset outside of the connection and then send it as a parameter to the update macro. Is this possible?

I have tried looking at the solutions found for in memory recordsets but these seemes to focus more on creating the columns rather than column-value pairs.

```vb
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim serverName As String
Dim dataBase As String

Dim forecastDate As Date
Dim projectNum As Long
Dim SqlStr As String

Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset

Set ws = ActiveSheet

serverName = "Servername"
dataBase = "database"

forecastDate = ws.Cells(2, "B").Value
projectNum = ws.Cells(3, "B").Value
SqlStr = "SELECT * From forecast WHERE forecastDate='" & forecastDate & "' AND projectNum = '" & projectNum & "';"

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst!forecastDate = forecastDate
rst!projectNum = projectNum
rst!Data = Cells(4, "B").Value


Application.Run "updateMacro", serverName, dataBase, SqlStr, rst
rst.Close

End Sub


'Part of the updateMacro:

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
cs = "DRIVER=SQL Server;DATABASE=" & dataBase & ";SERVER=" & serverName & ";Trusted_connection=yes;"
conn.Open cs

'Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open SqlStr, conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic 'adLockPessimistic

If rst.EOF Then
    rst.AddNew
End If

'get the recordset from caller macro and update

rst.Update

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
```

I would like to create the recordset outside of the updateMacro and use it in that macro or create some sort of column-value pairs that could be copied to the recordset in the updateMacro.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the recordset as global or also pass the recordset between functions/subs. Please see code below for an example:

```vb
Option Explicit

'Global Recordset to be sued by other functions
Private rsMain As ADODB.Recordset

Public Function ImportData(ByVal fyYear As String) As Long

    Dim sConnString As String, sqlYears As String
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim tCount As Long

    sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=server2;" & "Initial Catalog=FPSA;" & "Integrated Security=SSPI;"

    sqlYears = "select ltrim(rtrim(FinYearDesc)) as FinYearDesc, Month, AccountType, ltrim(rtrim(AccountName))as AccountName, " & _
              "ActualValue, BudgetValue from [GL_AccountMovements] where FinYearDesc >= '" & fyYear & "'"

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rsMain = New ADODB.Recordset

    rsMain.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rsMain.Open sqlYears, conn, _
         ADODB.adOpenForwardOnly, _
         ADODB.adLockBatchOptimistic

    Set rsMain.ActiveConnection = Nothing

    conn.Close

    If Not rsMain.EOF Then
        tCount = rsMain.RecordCount
    End If

    ImportData = tCount

End Function
'An example of using Global Recordset
Function GetAccountsByYearMonth(ByVal strYTDLastYear as String) As Double

    Dim lastYearYTDAct As Double

    rsMain.Filter = strYTDLastYear
    Do While Not rsMain.EOF
        lastYearYTDAct = lastYearYTDAct + rsMain.Fields("ActualValue")
        rsMain.MoveNext
    Loop

    GetAccountsByYearMonth = lastYearYTDAct

End Function
```

Thanks